# I am using 3 phones in China iPhone 5 iPhone 6s and xiaomi metal. I am coming to india, will it create some problem at the airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cellphones

Is there any customs problem while checking at the airport?

Comment: As a practical matter, customs enforcement at Indian airport is less stringent than the security at Indian shopping malls.  They x-ray your stuff, but they are looking for guns and bombs, not cell-phones.  (The malls x-ray your stuff, put you through a metal detector, *and* frisk you.  Really!)